# Pagination function in view returns all data in JSON after click search button

Tags: php, json, laravel, search, pagination

This function returns pages in my view but after click search button and filter columns it returns JSON with data from all columns.

```
{!! $data ?? ''->appends(request()->except('page'))->render() !!}
```

This is search function in my controller:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $search = $request->get('search');
    

    $requestData = ['surname', 'email', 'showname', 'business'];
   

    $data2 = User::where(function($q) use($requestData, $search) {
                foreach ($requestData as $field)
                   $q->orWhere($field, 'like', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(5);
        })->get();
    
    return view('users.index', ['data' => $data2])->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with deleting this json from view?

Answer (score 2):

you need to improve and fix your code:

```
  $query = User::query();
  foreach ($requestData as $field){
     $query->orWhere($field, 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
  }
  $data2=$query->paginate(5);
```